# Make http get request when iOs swift app loads

Tags: ios, iphone, json, swift, http

I making an iOs app in xcode to understand the whole development process. So far I have managed to load data to tableview from an array manually hard coded. Now I am trying to load content from a json I have hosted elsewhere. But till now I had no luck with the same.

My code as of now is below:

```
import UIKit
```

class FriendListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

let myFriends = ["Safwan Erooth", "Nadir K", "Salsabeel",  "Raheema"]

var selectedFriends = "Safwan"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.myFriends.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    cell.textLabel!.text = myFriends[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    self.selectedFriends = myFriends[indexPath.row]

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("friendListToFriendDetailSegue", sender: self)
}




override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! FriendDetailViewController

    detailViewController.name = self.selectedFriends

    if self.selectedFriends == "Safwan Erooth"  {

    detailViewController.birthday = "17 Nov"

    } else if self.selectedFriends == "Nadir K" {

    detailViewController.birthday = "10 Jan"

    } else if self.selectedFriends == "Salsabeel" {

        detailViewController.birthday = "12 June"

    } else if self.selectedFriends == "Raheema" {

        detailViewController.birthday = "16 Dec"

    }

  }

 }
```

I tried few examples in [this link][1] using the swift playgroubd. But its not working. The code i am trying in playground is this:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/test.json")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
    print(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
}
```

I get the following error in console.

```
Oct 22 11:20:22  MyPlayground[1989] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Oct 22 11:20:22  MyPlayground[1989] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Oct 22 11:20:22  MyPlayground[1989] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
Playground execution failed: /var/folders/cg/5wt2_vvx1mg5h73flw26gmvr0000gp/T/./lldb/312/playground6.swift:13:26: error: value of optional type 'NSData?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
    print(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
                         ^
```

What would be the best way to achieve what am trying to do?

**Update 1**

Added ! sign at the end of data as per answer given below, but i still get the below error.

```
2015-10-22 11:42:26.472 MyPlayground[22151:11326178] Failed to obtain sandbox extension for path=/var/folders/cg/5wt2_vvx1mg5h73flw26gmvr0000gp/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/containers/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.iOS_Simulator.MyPlayground-42AD40EC-8F3C-470F-B8AE-C9F4AF644932/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.iOS_Simulator.MyPlayground-42AD40EC-8F3C-470F-B8AE-C9F4AF644932. Errno:1
2015-10-22 11:42:26.472 MyPlayground[22151:11326178] Failed to obtain sandbox extension for path=/var/folders/cg/5wt2_vvx1mg5h73flw26gmvr0000gp/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/containers/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.iOS_Simulator.MyPlayground-42AD40EC-8F3C-470F-B8AE-C9F4AF644932/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.iOS_Simulator.MyPlayground-42AD40EC-8F3C-470F-B8AE-C9F4AF644932. Errno:1\
```

**Update 2**

Tried the below code:

```
 let components = NSURLComponents()
                    components.scheme = "http"
                    components.host = "localhost"
                    components.path = "/test.json"


                    let sessionURL = components.URL!

                    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: sessionURL)

                    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

                    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {

                        (data, response, error) -> Void in

                        if error == nil{
    //then save json to a variable/constant
//this casts the son to an array of dictionaries
     yourJSON = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves) as! [NSDictionary]

        }

        }
        task.resume()
```

But got an error `error: use of unresolved identifier 'yourJSON'`

**Also tried below code:**

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://httpbin.org/get")
let request:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL:url)
let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ response, data, error in /* Your code */ })
```

But got the error:

```
error: value of optional type 'NSURL?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
```

And

```
warning: 'sendAsynchronousRequest(_:queue:completionHandler:)' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use [NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:]
```

Comment: check that the URL in Browser, the URL Contains Data or not and then try your code , I checked your URL in browser , the browser says its invalid URL, try in valid URL surely u get answer

Comment: The url is in my localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has deprecated the NSURLConnection methods and you should now use NSURLSession instead.

Try This

```
    let components = NSURLComponents()
                    components.scheme = "http"
                    components.host = "localhost"
                    components.path = "/test.json"


                    let sessionURL = components.URL!

                    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: sessionURL)

                    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

                    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {

                        (data, response, error) -> Void in

                        if error == nil{
    //then save json to a variable/constant
//this casts the son to an array of dictionaries
   let   <#yourJSON#> = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves) as! [NSDictionary]


        }

        }
        task.resume()
```

Comment: I still get error, I have updated the question. Please check.

Comment: I am getting this error `error: use of unresolved identifier 'yourJSON'`

Comment: Put let before yourJSON so let yourJSON

Comment: Why are you making it more difficult than it needs to be? I told you NSURLconnection was deprecated which is why I have gave you the NSURLSession code instead. The error: use of unresolved identifier 'yourJSON'  is because yourJSON was a clue for you to add your own name to the variable/ constant as would be more fitting for your code to use. I have edited the code so you can copy paste as that appears to be all you are capable of doing anyway.

Comment: Am sorry for testing your patience. This is my first attempt at using both Swift language and Xcode. Sorry about that. I really appreciate the time you took out. With experience only on php and js Swift is very challenging but fun to learn. I have accepted your answer too. Maybe you can consider removing the down vote.

Comment: @esafwan down vote is locked unless question is edited.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `!` sign at the end of `data`:

```
print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
```

and it will work ;)

**UPDATE**

```
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "your_url_here")
let request:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL:url)
let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ response, data, error in /* Your code */ })
```

Comment: @RyanTCB that's what console log says

Comment: Yeah I said that too :)

Comment: @esafwan can you change your url to: `let url = NSURL(string: "http://httpbin.org/get")`? May be your error because of your localhost

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade Sorry, I am checking now. I was out for some work. Thanks

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade It didn't work. I got 2 error messages.  
Error 1:
`error: value of optional type 'NSURL?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?`
Error two:
` warning: 'sendAsynchronousRequest(_:queue:completionHandler:)' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use [NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:]`